# Why we don't use a pointer in Cs50 pset4 filter's grayscale function?

Tags: c, function, pointers, cs50

Why we don't use a pointer in helpers.c? I noticed that check50 has passed for my code below, but how does it convert the variable "image" in filter.c?

```
#include "helpers.h"

// Convert image to grayscale

    void grayscale(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
    {
        float tmp;
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            {
                tmp = (image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j].rgbtGreen)/3.0;
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = (int)(tmp + 0.5);
                image[i][j].rgbtRed = (int)(tmp + 0.5);
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = (int)(tmp + 0.5);
            }
        }
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are writing to a file when you set the values of `image[i][j].rgbtBlue, image[i][j].rgbtGreen, image[i][j].rgbtRed.`

What are the following lines of your code inside the double loop doing?

```
image[i][j].rgbtBlue = (int)(tmp + 0.5);
image[i][j].rgbtRed = (int)(tmp + 0.5);
image[i][j].rgbtGreen = (int)(tmp + 0.5);
```

They are changing the bitmap image file pixel by pixel. The file is in **secondary memory**. It doesn't relate to pointers of the variables or their addresses in **main memory**.